# DateTime::getTimezone doesn't return timezone name, but offset

Tags: php, datetime

```
<?php
$first = '2011-04-27';
$second = '2011-04-27 16:20:12';
$third = '2011-04-27 16:20:12+00';

$dt = new DateTime($first);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($dt->getTimeZone()->getName()));
echo $dt->getTimezone()->getName().'<br />';
// OK
$dt = new DateTime($second);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($dt->getTimeZone()->getName()));
echo $dt->getTimezone()->getName().'<br />';
// OK
$dt = new DateTime($third);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($dt->getTimeZone()->getName()));
echo $dt->getTimezone()->getName().'<br />';
// Error
// ->getName() returns unexpectedly +00, which is not a name, but offset
```

DateTime extracts from the last string timezone **name** `+00`, which is really not **name**, but **offset** and therefore cannot be set as timezone...

This behavior is causing troubles when (de)serializing DateTime object...

```
public function __sleep()
{
    $this->fix = array($this->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $this->getTimezone()->getName());
    return array('fix');
}

public function __wakeup()
{
    $this->__construct($this->fix[0], new DateTimeZone($this->fix[1]));
    unset($this->fix);
}
```

I know it would be better to get e.g. this string: `2011-04-27 16:20:12 UTC`, anyway as far as the metod is called `getName()`, it shouldn't return `+00` as a name, or should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried to create `DateTime` object with timezone offset `+00`, that's why it returned offset instead of valid timezone identifier and actually that means `GMT+0000`. Using datetime string without offset you'll get PHP timezone identifier according to current timezone setting in DateTime object (or system).

With `$third = '2011-04-27 16:20:12+00';` you have set `+00:00` offset in `DateTime` object instead of PHP identifier and `DateTime` just returns that back with `->getName()` method.

Fixed offset doesn't provide information about DST rules so it can't be used to get back PHP TimeZone identifier. Example: In my zone it's `GMT+2` at the moment (active DST) but if I put it in datetime string, DateTime object can't know when my offset changes to `+1`, simply, it's always GMT+0200... that's all.

Offset `+00` in your case matches a lot of different timezone identifiers like `Atlantic/Reykjavík`, `Africa/Casablanca`, `Africa/Nouakchott`, etc.

**That's why getName() method returns time offset instead of timezone!**

This is not official explanation, but that's it in short version.

Of course, `2011-04-27 16:20:12+00` is not valid datetime string.

Answer (score 0):

When I run that code, PHP says it doesn't recognize that format (formats are defined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)) so the output is as a result of an error. However, I was able to run it like so:

```
$third = '2011-04-27 16:20:12 GMT';

$dt = new DateTime($third);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($dt->getTimeZone()->getName()));
echo $dt->getTimezone()->getName().'<br />';
```

I think you can just replace `+00` with just `GMT`.

Comment: I can write some piece of code, which will replace +00 with UTC or GMT, or i can set database to return timezone names, but that's not my point... my point is "Why getName() method returns offset"?

Comment: What Wh1T3h4Ck5 says is correct, it's because the `getName` function can't resolve your offset to a timezone defined in PHP.